# GraphQL query in Javascript

Tags: graphql, github-actions

I'm currently trying to move my Postman queries into production. I have this query here.
[image: Postman]

I'd like to add this to my Node package that runs as a GH Action.

```js
const core = require("@actions/core");
const github = require("@actions/github");
const { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const run = async () => {
  /** The token used to access Gatsby Cloud */
  const gatsbyToken = core.getInput("gatsby-token");
  /** The ID of the site to modify */
  const siteID = core.getInput("gatsby-site-id");
  /** The GraphQL schema used to query the existing ENV */
  const schema = buildSchema(`
    query AllEnvironmentVariablesForSite($id: UUID!) {
      buildEnvironmentVariablesForSite: environmentVariablesForSite(
        id: $id
        runnerType: BUILDS
      ) {
        key
        value
        truncatedValue
      }
      previewEnvironmentVariablesForSite: environmentVariablesForSite(
        id: $id
        runnerType: PREVIEW
      ) {
        key
        value
        truncatedValue
      }
    }
  `);
  /** The variables associated to the GraphQL schema above */
  const variables = {
    id: siteID
  }
  console.log( { variables } )
  try {
    /** The existing ENV in Gatsby Cloud */
    const existing = await fetch( 'https://api.gatsbyjs.com/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${gatsbyToken}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify( { query, variables } )
    } )
  } catch ( error ) {
    core.setFailed( error.message )
  }
}

run()
```

When I run this locally, I get the error that UUID is an unknown type: `Unknown type "UUID".`.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that the query should be formatted as a string. The question has the query formatted as it would be in the express server.

```js
...
  /** The GraphQL schema used to query the existing ENV */
  const query = `
    query AllEnvironmentVariablesForSite($id: UUID!) {
      buildEnvironmentVariablesForSite: environmentVariablesForSite(
        id: $id
        runnerType: BUILDS
      ) {
        key
        value
        truncatedValue
      }
      previewEnvironmentVariablesForSite: environmentVariablesForSite(
        id: $id
        runnerType: PREVIEW
      ) {
        key
        value
        truncatedValue
      }
    }`
...
try {
    /** The existing ENV in Gatsby Cloud */
    const existing = await fetch( 'https://api.gatsbyjs.com/graphql', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${gatsbyToken}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify( { query, variables } )
    } )
    const existingJSON  = await existing.json()
    console.log( existingJSON.data )
  } catch ( error ) {
    core.setFailed( error.message )
  }
}
```